# Conditions for a set to be not connected in a topological space, found in Section 10.1 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis

Tags: general-topology

In the section 10.1 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, a set $E$ in a topological space $X$ is said to be not connected if $E$ is the union of two nonempty sets $A$ and $B$ such that $\overline{A}\cap B = \emptyset = A\cap\overline{B}$.
Then, it is mentioned that if there exist open sets $V$ and $W$ satisfying $E\subset V\cup W$, $E\cap V \neq \emptyset$, $E\cap W\neq\emptyset$, and $E\cap V\cap W = \emptyset$, then it is easy to see that $E$ is not connected, by taking $A = E\cap W$ and $B = E\cap V$.
However, I have some difficulties to prove it.
I can only show $\overline{A}\cap B \subset E \cap V \cap \overline{W}$ and $A\cap\overline{B}\subset E\cap\overline{V}\cap W$.
Would you give me any hint?

Comment: Hint: if you have two open sets $A$, $B$, and $A \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset$ then $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $V$ and $W$ are open sets, $V\cap E$ and $W\cap E$ are open subsets of $E$. Therefore, their complements in $E$ are closed subsets of $E$. But, since $E\setminus(E\cap V)=E\cap W$ and $E\setminus(E\cap W)=E\cap V$. So, $V\cap E$ and $W\cap E$ are also closed subsets of $E$. But then, in $E$, $\overline{E\cap V}=E\cap V$ and $\overline{E\cap W}=E\cap W$. So, since $(E\cap V)\cap(E\cap W)=\emptyset$, you also have$$\overline{(E\cap V)}\cap(E\cap W)=\emptyset\text{ and }(E\cap V)\cap\overline{(E\cap W)}=\emptyset.$$

Comment: No, the closure should be taken in $E$. *Everything* takes place in $E$.

Comment: So, do you mean, even in the condition $\overline{A}\cap B = \emptyset = A\cap \overline{B}$, the closures are taken in $E$?

Comment: Yes, “everything” includes that.

Comment: However, Rudin did not introduce the subspace topology up to this part, so I am not sure if the closure is really taken in $E$. I will have some time to think about it before I accept your answer.

Comment: I could figure out that $A\cap V = B\cap W = E\cap V\cap W = \emptyset$ implies $\overline{A}\subset V^c$ and $\overline{B}\subset W^c$. Since $A\subset W$ and $B\subset V$, we have $\overline{A}\cap B = \emptyset = A\cap\overline{B}$. Thus, we can prove that $E$ is not connected without introducing the subspace topology. However, your answer looks more standard in Topology.